# Pass Argument to Python Script in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: python, windows, parameter-passing, command-prompt, arcpy

I'm trying to pass an argument to python via windows command prompt, but am encountering the following error:

`[Errno 22] Invalid argument`

**Command Prompt Code:**

`C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\recipe.py C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\input1.txt"`

Comment: try `C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\recipe.py" "C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\input1.txt"`

Comment: Thanks for getting back, sadly this didnt work, still throwing an error.

Comment: You need the quotes as @iwin suggests. If you're still getting an error, edit your question to include the complete traceback.

Comment: Thank you all, found the error traced back to missing one folder for the python.exe file. FIgures................

Answer (score 0):

You are missing both a closing and opening `"`'s:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe 
"C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\recipe.py" 
"C:\Users\Apples\Documents\ArcGIS\Grapes\Blueberry_Cobbler\input1.txt"
```